# How checkpatch.pl work and what exactly we can get by running it on a patch?

Tags: linux, git

I am very new to Linux and Git. I want to know what exactly `checkpatch.pl` script does. I know there is a source code available on the Internet but it's a Perl script and I don't know Perl.

So, can anyone here explain me here what exactly does it do?

Comment: This link might help http://www.tuxradar.com/content/newbies-guide-hacking-linux-kernel

Answer (score 5):

It is a tool to check your coding style match Linux coding style or not. You can use -help to see what options you can use. After it check your file, the tool prints a result like compile result. The result show you which line has coding style errors and warnings, and reminds you how to modify your code. And also you can modify the script tool to match your own coding style.

Answer (score 2):

[checkpatch.pl](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/checkpatch.pl) is a script in the kernel tree that facilitates better kernel code, and can be used to check many coding style rules. This script applies on patch files by default, but can also process complete source files using the `-f` or `--file` option.

See:

```
scripts/checkpatch.pl -h # running from kernel source root
```

or

```
checkpatch.pl -h --no-tree # when pwd ≠ root of the kernel source
```

Answer (score 0):

checkpatch.pl is mainly used to verify stylistic coding conventions so that anyone attempting to submit code upstream into the Linux kernel will be sure to have met the basic coding style requirements by running this script first (and, if possible, have no resulting errors or warnings).  It also has some basic programming safeguards built into it that will flag potentially dangerous/erroneous lines in your code in order to prevent you from attempting to upstream code that will compile but will not be accepted upstream (in most cases).

You can find checkpatch.pl in the link below along with some other useful scripts for Linux kernel developers:
[Linux Kernel Scripts](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/scripts)

Once you obtain the script, be sure to run "chmod 777 checkpatch.pl" on it before attempting to run it.

As [Skynet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3892259/skynet) mentioned already, you can use it on patches or source files.  Just be sure to use the correct flag(s) when you run the script, you can see a list of the script's options by running "checkpatch.pl -h" which will display the help manual for the script.